# How can I create a 4D numpy array from images?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have some images that I'm converting into 3D numpy arrays. I would like to aggregate all of these image arrays into one big numpy array (such that index 0 of this big array is the 3D numpy array representing my image).

What is the best way to do this?

My image shape looks like this:

```
(128, 128, 3) # shape of each image
[[[119  95  59]
  [118  94  58]
  [120  96  60]
  ...
  [110  89  51]
  [111  89  54]
  [116  93  61]]

 [[136 112  76]
  [139 115  79]
  [141 117  81]
  ...
  [114  93  55]
  [119  97  62]
  [114  91  59]]

 [[127 103  67]
  [127 103  67]
  [134 110  74]
  ...
  [110  89  51]
  [115  93  57]
  [119  97  62]]

 ...

 [[116  92  68]
  [105  83  55]
  [109  87  52]
  ...
  [119  99  58]
  [125 102  64]
  [120  97  59]]

 [[111  90  68]
  [111  89  64]
  [105  84  53]
  ...
  [123 101  60]
  [121  96  56]
  [129 104  64]]

 [[109  90  69]
  [105  85  60]
  [105  84  56]
  ...
  [121  99  58]
  [128 102  62]
  [129 104  62]]]
```

Comment: Did you try `np.dstack(list_of_images)`?

Comment: `What is the best way to do this?` *one that works* - [Joining Arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html#joining-arrays)

Comment: I just tried that and I get the error: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 3):

If all the image arrays have the same shape, such as (128, 128, 3), then `np.stack` will do nicely

```
np.stack(alist_images, axis=0)
```

should produce a (n, 128, 128, 3) array.

Actually `np.array(alist_images)` should also work, but `stack` lets you pick another axis to join them on, e.g. (128, 128, 3, n)

If it complains about dimensions not matching, then you don't have a list of matching arrays.